# Get raw data in symfony 2 request

Tags: post, symfony, request

i'm trying to get some HTML code in a post Request with the symfony 2 API.

For example when i post something like "< p > hello < / p > "

I got in my request action handler (using $request->request->get(X)) an escaped string => "p hello /p"

Is there any way to get the raw data in the action handler ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$request->request->get(X)` [doesn't escape values](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.php#L90-L150). To view posted data use [Profiler](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/internals.html#profiler). Your data are escaped by something else.